# Wordpress $wpdb update not working when mounted inside function?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

```php
$wpdb-> update('Gen3', array( 'tvalue' => "1"), array('id' => 1));
```

Table:

| id | name | tvalue |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 25 | #25 | 0 |

I want to change tvalue to 1. But I cannot get my code to work.

I tried many options and neither of them works.

This is my full code:

```js
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'mycustom_wp_footer' );

    function mycustom_wp_footer() {
        ?>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var wpcf7Elm = document.querySelectorAll( '.wpcf7' );
            wpcf7Elm.forEach(function(formr){
            formr.addEventListener( 'wpcf7submit', function( event ) {
                    //if ('wpcf7-f101-p97-o1' == event.detail.unitTag) {

                        $wpdb->update(
                          'Gen3', // This should be the name of your table
                          array(
                            'tvalue' => '1',  // string with quotation  // integer (number) without quotation
                          ),
                          array('ID' => 25), // The id of the row you're trying to update
                          array(
                            '%s'   // The format of the value you're trying to update. // Use '%d' if it's a number
                          ),
                          array('%d') // The format of the where clause which is the id of the row you're trying to update
                        );
                                            //}
                    //var idform = event.detail.unitTag;
                    //alert (idform);
            }, false ); })
        </script>
        <?php
    }
```

Comment: Please share more details. That code does not look like valid PHP code, as `$wpdb` is not a JS variable

Comment: This is code form functions.php. It should update database when button inside form is cliked,

Comment: Well, it won't, as you cannot call PHP functions within JS code

Comment: Yes, I just find it out. Didn´t know about it. I am going to try find way how to combine this.  Thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I highly suggest to read the "Docs" first. It'll get your problem solved much faster. It's all in here:

> [`UPDATE rows`<sup>Docs</sup>](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/#update-rows)

Also in your snippet, you've set your `'id' => 1` which is incorrect according to the table you've provided, the id you're interested in, is `25`!

Also make sure, you're using the right format for the values in the query. It's very important to use `'%s'` and `'%d'` correctly, otherwise it won't work!

Note, I capitalized the `ID` of your row according to the documentation page, if it does not work, then use the lowercase `id`.

```php
$wpdb->update(
  'Gen3', // This should be the name of your table
  array(
    'tvalue' => '1',  // string with quotation  // integer (number) without quotation
  ),
  array('ID' => 25), // The id of the row you're trying to update
  array(
    '%s'   // The format of the value you're trying to update. // Use '%d' if it's a number
  ),
  array('%d') // The format of the where clause which is the id of the row you're trying to update
);
```

Let me know if you were able to get it to work!

Comment: I have found the problem. It was not the code it self. The problem is that php code cannot be inside Js. Anyway, thank you for your help!

Comment: Great that you found the bug! At the time I provided an answer you hadn't mentioned anything about your javascript snippet. It was not even part of your question. It's good that your problem solved!

Answer (score 1):

Use this instead of `$wpdb->update()`

```
$wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("UPDATE $table_name SET tvalue='1' WHERE id=%d", 1));
```

Comment: It´s still not working. This raw sql code that I want to work: UPDATE `Gen3` SET `tvalue`='1' WHERE 25

Comment: @Entity_45 you meant `WHERE id = 25`

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it. What did you change, and why?